# Convert string into mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: c#, date

I have following strings in different formats:

```
16/05/2014
21-Jun-2014
2014-05-16
16-05-2014
5/19/2014
14 May 2014
```

I need to convert all the above strings into mm/dd/yyyy format in c#.
I have tried used `DateTime.ParseExact` as `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("16-05-2014", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` in C# but i am getting the exception as "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

I have also tried to use to `Convert.ToDateTime()` but it is also not working.

Is there any method or function that we can write/available in C# that would convert the above string formats into a single date format i.e into "mm/dd/yyyy" format ??

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the documentation to learn what `mm` means.  (hint: Minutes and Months are not the same)

Comment: Your format string doesn't seem to match the input.  `/` and `-` are different characters, and the input doesn't have any time specification.  You probably want the format string to actually *match* the format of the date...

Comment: On your example `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("16-05-2014", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, the format of the date is actually, "dd/mm/yyyy".  Try something simple like DateTime.ParseExact("16-05-2014", "dd/mm/yyyy") and see if it works. From there, what you may need to do if you have different formats is  try converting with one format, and if you get an exception, convert using another.

Comment: You are using `ParseExact` the wrong way round. You should be telling the function what format the input string is in, not what format the output will be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Is it possible to convert the string as "16-05-2014" into "05/16/2014" format using DateTime.ParseExact method or any other methods available in C# or do i need to write a function explicitly ?

Comment: Stop writing Java code. It rots your mind. Not every object is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails on the very first term of your format string, which is telling the function to treat the "16" as minutes and to look for hours, minutes, and seconds that don't exist in the input.

You have several different date formats, and so need the [ParseExact() overload that accepts several different format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx):

```
string[] formats= {"dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                   "dd-MM-yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "dd MMM yyyy"};
string converted = DateTime.ParseExact("16-05-2014", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Also remember that lower case "m"s are for minutes. If you want months, you need an upper case "M". Full documentation on format strings is here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Finally, I suspect you are getting ahead of yourself on formatting the output as a string. Keep these values as DateTime objects for as long as possible, and only format to a string at the last possible moment before showing them to the user. If you really do want a string, at least stick with the [ISO 8601 standard format.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that your format string is wrong. A small `m` is for minute, a big `M` is for month.
Try to pass all your formats in an array. For example like this

```
DateTime.ParseExact("16-05-2014",
                    new[] {"dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                        "dd-MM-yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "dd MMM yyyy"},
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

With this you can parse all your formats at once.
For more information about the format settings, see the official [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

On a `DateTime` object you can call `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`. Given the strings you have, you can first create new `DateTime` objects for each string and then call `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`. For example:

```
var dateAsMmDdYyyy = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

Your input date `16/05/2014` doesn't match your format `Month/Day/Year` - how can there be a 16th month?

Secondly, you're using `mm` which represents `Minutes`, not `Months`. You should use `MM`.

Finally, your sample string `16-05-2014` doesn't match the format provided, you've used hyphens `-` instead of forward slashes `/`

Supply a collection of different formats matching your input:

```
string[] formats = new [] { "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", 
                            "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd MMM yyyy" };
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("05-16-2014", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following method useful to accept whatever date format you want and convert it to DateTime:

```
public DateTime? DTNullable(string DateTimestring, string CurrDateTimeFormat)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateTimestring)) return null;
    else
    {
        DateTime datetimeNotNull;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(DateTimestring, CurrDateTimeFormat, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeNotNull);
        return datetimeNotNull;
    }
}
```

Pass in your desired string to be converted to DateTime along with it's current date time format and this would return you a nullable DateTime. If you're certain that whatever string you're passing in won't be null then you can remove that bit. The reason for it being there is that you can't convert a null to DateTime. In my case I couldn't be certain if it would be or not so I needed the ability to capture nulls as well.

You can use it like this:

```
DateTime? MyDateTime = DTNullable(MyStartDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If you wanted you could alter the method to accept an array of strings and simply iterate through each and return them all in a list if they were of the same format.

As others have pointed out, months are MM not mm (minutes).